# Networking service down, ifup --all causes error

Tags: networking, server, configuration, services

Please help me get the network back to my server, basically, I can't do something like `sudo apt update, git pull`, and other things, it just gets connection timeout.

My networking service is 'failed' it is not working, when I try to start it `sudo /etc/init.d/networking start`, it gives me:

```
Starting networking (via systemctl): networking.serviceJob 
for networking.service failed because the control process 
exited with error code. See "systemctl status 
networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!
```

if I try to reload it, `sudo /etc/init.d/networking reload`:

```
Reloading network interfaces configuration...                                
ifup: no interface(s) specified
ifup: Use --help for help
```

if I do `sudo ifup --all` that's what I get:

```
/etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail: 44: .: Can't open /usr/share/sendmail/dynamic
run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail exited with return code 2
Failed to bring up lo.
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0:0.
/etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail: 44: .: Can't open /usr/share/sendmail/dynamic
run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail exited with return code 2
ifup: post-up script failed.*\
```

That is my interfaces file:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface



auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

this is `sudo /etc/init.d/networking status`:

```
networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
        /etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: **failed** (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-05-08 16:12:22 EDT; 5min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 19969 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment **(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**
  Process: 19961 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19969 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 08 16:12:22 s....secureserver.net ifup[19969]: Failed to bring up eth0.
May 08 16:12:22 s....secureserver.net ifup[19969]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 08 16:12:22 s....secureserver.net ifup[19969]: Failed to bring up eth0:0.
May 08 16:12:22 s....secureserver.net ifup[19969]: /etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail: 44: .: Can't open /usr/share/sen...namic
May 08 16:12:22 s....secureserver.net ifup[19969]: run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail exited with return code 2
May 08 16:12:22 s....secureserver.net systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 08 16:12:22 s....secureserver.net ifup[19969]: /sbin/ifup: post-up script failed.
May 08 16:12:22 s....secureserver.net systemd[1]: **Failed to start Raise network interfaces.**
May 08 16:12:22 s....secureserver.net systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 08 16:12:22 s....secureserver.net systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

`ifconfig -a`:

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ****************  
              inet addr:************  Bcast:**************  Mask:255.255.*******
              inet6 addr: *********************** Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:****  Metric:1
              RX packets:2973672 errors:0 dropped:85624 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:203653 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:244631493 (244.6 MB)  TX bytes:117977760 (117.9 MB)

    eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ***************** 
              inet addr:****************  Bcast:****************  Mask:255.255.255.255
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:****  Metric:1

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::****** Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:*******  Metric:1
              RX packets:99855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:99855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
              RX bytes:38028421 (38.0 MB)  TX bytes:38028421 (38.0 MB)
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sudo ip addr flush dev lo
sudo ifdown --all
sudo ifup --all
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: lo doesn't solve the problem, but I will try this with eth0 and eth0:0